# RegEx to match any url with given path but not finishing with the word 'search'

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to build a regular expression that groups all page urls with the following path but that don't end with the word 'search'.

After environment, drug-misuse and communicable-diseases anything can follow but search.

I've tried several things similar to the following expression without success:

^/health-protection/(environment|drug-misuse|communicable-diseases)/(?!search).*$

I hope it makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards, Alex

Comment: GA regex engine is RE2, and it does not support lookarounds at all.

Comment: I want any url that starts with the pattern I have given but the ones finishing with 'search'

Comment: Please add some examples that should and some that should not match. Also note that GA help page on "View Filters" mentions that it can take up to 24h for a filter to take effect.

Comment: @alex_cargo I would like to know which of the following urls are not allowed: `/health-protection/environment/searchX`, `/health-protection/environment/Xsearch`, `/health-protection/environment/XsearchX`

Comment: An example would be /conditions-and-diseases/cardiovascular-conditions/search thanks, A.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following regex:

```
^/health-protection/(environment|drug-misuse|communicable-diseases)/.*([^s].{5}|s[^e].{4}|se[^a].{3}|sea[^r].{2}|sear[^c].|searc[^h])$
```

Comment: Hi Horcrux, that didn't work either unfortunately. Thanks, A.